Understanding $MyInvocation.MyCommand members
The Path, Definition, and Source members of $MyInvocation.MyCommand are all identical. Is this always the case? Under what conditions would the be different? What is the purpose of each?
The ScriptBlock and ScriptContents members are identical. What is the purpose of each?
PS C:\src\t> cat .\Do-InvocationSettings.ps1
$MyInvocation.MyCommand | Format-List * -Force
return 0
PS C:\src\t> .\Do-InvocationSettings.ps1

HelpUri            :
Path               : C:\src\t\Do-InvocationSettings.ps1
Definition         : C:\src\t\Do-InvocationSettings.ps1
Source             : C:\src\t\Do-InvocationSettings.ps1
Visibility         : Public
ScriptBlock        : $MyInvocation.MyCommand | Format-List * -Force
                     return 0
OutputType         : {}
ScriptContents     : $MyInvocation.MyCommand | Format-List * -Force
                     return 0
OriginalEncoding   : System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed
Name               : Do-InvocationSettings.ps1
CommandType        : ExternalScript
Version            :
ModuleName         :
Module             :
RemotingCapability : PowerShell
Parameters         : {}
ParameterSets      : {}

My apologies for including a picture. Why does VS Code only display four (4) of the members of $MyInvocation.MyCommand?


ScriptBlock and OutputType are properties of the ScriptInfo type (as returned by $MyInvocation.MyCommand in your case) as well  - they're at the same nested level as Path, Definition, Source and Visibility but because they're objects rather than strings they've got a leading > which can be expanded. At first glance it kind of throws the eye and makes it look like they're at the same level in the tree as MyCommand, but they're nested under it...
